# SQL multiple joins error

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a temporary table with information from the orders table in. I then want to join stock.name, and most of the supplier information using the supplier ID which is the foreign key in the orders table. This is my code below, but I seem to get an error in access.

This query will be run in VB to create a temporary table to pass over data to excel. The table should only store one record but should be deleted soon after excel takes the data from it. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me.

```
SELECT orders.purchase_order_number, orders.part_number, stock.name, orders.quantity,     orders.order_date, suppliers.last_name, suppliers.first_name, suppliers.address_1,     suppliers.address_2, suppliers.city, suppliers.postcode 
INTO order_temp FROM orders 
INNER JOIN suppliers ON orders.supplier_ID = suppliers.supplier_ID 
INNER JOIN stock ON orders.part_number = stock.part_number
WHERE orders.purchase_order_number = 'PO10367'  and suppliers.supplier_ID = 20
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are querying from VB (such as VB.net), then when you query to your LOCAL VB app from the connection, you do not need to select into table...  The error you are probably getting is that the table already exists and can't recreate it, it must be dropped... But if you just query to VB app, and no table created, you should be good to go.